# Create a table with a single column in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Why does this not work?

```
cell2table({1;2;3},'RowNames',{'test'})
```

I have defined the data to be a cell column vector of numbers, and have specified a single heading.

I get the error:

**Error using cell2table (line 58)
The RowNames property must contain one name for each row in the table.**

Comment: You would need three row names, because the cell has three rows. Perhaps you mean `cell2table({1 2 3},'RowNames',{'test'})`?

Comment: you have three rows. you need three names.

Comment: If you want to set column name, `cell2table({1;2;3},'VariableNames',{'test'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creating a table with 1 row and 3 columns and the row named 'test':

```
cell2table({1 2 3},'RowNames',{'test'})
```

creating a table with 3 rows and 1 column and the cloumn named 'test':

```
cell2table({1;2;3},'VariableNames',{'test'})
```

you can also combine those, but `'Rownames'`length hast to equal the amount of rows and `'Variablenames'` length has to equal the amount of columns